# The workflow created too many large objects in a row, exceeding the limit of 100 megabytes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow, 2016, workflow-manager

I got this exception in runtime execution of mine SP2013 declarative workflow built as Visual Studio State Machine WF.
Help me with identifying the root source of problem.

I can think of the following options to look for as a solution:

1. Increasing memory quota per instance (WF Manager settings)
2. Localize variable to scope (assuming that WF Manager disposes them properly and don't leak)
3. Extract some logic into separate declarative Activity
4. Extract some logic into separate Workflow

Comment: honestly I can hardly imagine why a workflow can run in this exception. Would you mind to describe a little what this workflow does - I mean state machine, ok, but do you handle a huge mass of tasks or a huge set of list items or lookup fields or loops?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, yes, it was the loops issue. So if you have this error, first thing to check is to go through all loops in the workflow to ensure they have exit state.